# How to display the variable's name with the highest value in Java?

Tags: java

I created a voting system and the candidate with the most votes wins. I want to display the candidate's integer name rather than its value; however, I can't seem to find the right method. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
int largest = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(candidate1, candidate2, candidate3));
System.out.println("The winning candidate is " + largest + "!");
// Displays the value, rather than the integers name
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the integers name"?    The name of the variable that happens to hold the integer value?   Neither Collections.max nor Arrays.asList is away of those variables; they just see values.  You'll need to write code that keeps track of what you're interested in, so you know if variable candidate1 hold the maximum count, then "candidate1" (which is a string with no direct relationship to the name of the variable) is the string to print.   There are structures that will help with this, but given what I guess to be your experience level, I think you should code it "simply" to start.

Comment: Yes, I meant to refer to the variable's name rather than the value to be displayed. As I am not too experienced in such methods, I cannot find a simpler method. The code is very simple, however, how am I meant to write code that keeps track when all I'm trying to achieve in one line of code is returning the variable's name of the variable with the highest value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it that way.  I suggest a class.

```
class Candidate {
       String name;
       int votes = 0;
       // other required values here
       public Candidate(String name /* other values here */) {
          this.name = name;
          // other assignments.
       }

       public void addVotes(int v) {
           votes += v;
       }
       
       public int getVotes() {
           return votes;
       }
       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return name;
       }
    
}

List<Candidate> candidates = List.of(new Candidate("Mary"), new 
      Candidate("John"), new Candidate("Jim"));
candidates.get(0).addVotes(2);
candidates.get(1).addVotes(7);
candidates.get(2).addVotes(3);
```

The comparator compares the classes based on votes and returns that instance.

```
Candidate winner = Collections.max(candidates, 
                     Comparator.comparing(Candidate::getVotes));
System.out.println(winner + " with " + winner.getVotes() + " votes");
```

prints

```
John with 7 votes
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Candidate class, where you could have a property `name`, and `numberOfVotes`.

```
  public class Candidate implements Comparable<Candidate> {
     private String name;
     private Integer numberOfVotes;
     
     public Candidate(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        numberOfVotes = 0;
     }
     
     public String getName() {
        return name;
     }
     
     public void setNumberOfVotes(int numberOfVotes) {
        this.numberOfVotes = numberOfVotes;
     }
     
     public Integer getNumberOfVotes(){
        return numberOfVotes;
     }
     
     @Override
     public int compareTo(Candidate candidate){
        return numberOfVotes.compareTo(candidate.getNumberOfVotes());
     }
     
}
```

This way, the following would work:

```
Candidate winner = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(candidate1, candidate2, candidate3));
System.out.println("The winning candidate is " + winner.getName()+ "!");
```

Comment: In the future, please don't delete an answer and add another one.  Just edit your first and then undelete it.

Comment: I tried to undelete it, but I can't. It needs 5 votes to be undeleted.

Comment: Not certain what is going on.  See this [Can I undelete my own self-deleted post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262294/can-i-undelete-my-own-self-deleted-pos). If it doesn't work you can flag it for moderator intervention.

Comment: Just flagged it for intervention, I'm not sure what happened. I posted it initially by mistake, then deleted it so I could edit. When I was finished, I tried to undelete it, but it keeps showing a pop-up error.

Comment: Thank you this also satisfies the problem I had :)